# Hello, when i'm training my model with 80% data and testing with 20% data the accuracy is 49% and without split it's 99%

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training, accuracy

**Hello, when i'm training my model with 80% data and testing with 20% data the accuracy is 49%. And when i'm training my data without splitting it's giving around 99%. I'm confused. Please help me with this**

**The below code is with split which got 49% accuracy**

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"dataset.csv")

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()

objList = data.select_dtypes(include = "object").columns

for feat in objList:
    data[feat] = le.fit_transform(data[feat].astype(str))

X = data.iloc[:, data.columns != 'Outcome'].values
y = data.iloc[:, data.columns == 'Outcome'].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
randomforest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
randomforest.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = randomforest.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
```

**The below code is without split which got 99% accuracy**

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'dataset.csv')

le = LabelEncoder()

objList = data.select_dtypes(include = "object").columns

for feat in objList:
    data[feat] = le.fit_transform(data[feat].astype(str))

X = data.iloc[:, data.columns != 'Outcome'].values
y = data.iloc[:, data.columns == 'Outcome'].values

file = open(r'finalized_model.pkl', 'rb')

data = pickle.load(file)

y_pred = data.predict(X)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.accuracy_score(y, y_pred))
cm = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
print(cm)
```

Total data is the same used for 2 codes.

Answer (score 3):

When you split the data , you are training your model on 80 percent of the dataset , but you are finding the accuracy of the remaining 20 percent of the data.
And when you are not splitting the data your model is learning and calculating accuracy from a similar dataset , hence the accuracy is pretty high.

You should:
1.Always split the data and try to achieve high accuracy on the test set rather than the training set.
2.If your training data accuracy is quite higher than the test data this means your modell is overfitting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and i have one question. So i'm saving this trained model into a pickle file and running that pickle model on a new similar dataset and it's giving 65% accuracy. Will accuracy changes for every dataset? And in new data, i'm not splitting the data, i'm directly predicting

Comment: for the above comment - you are doing it right, accuracy comes different for different datasets. try reading about cross validation and why we use it. also the new data set(with 65% accuracy) must have less data (I hope) then the 20% data for which you were getting 49%. read about cross-validation and overfitting.

Comment: When your model will not generalize well (ie. due to overfitting), then the accuracy will differ a lot with different dataset. But if your correctly train your model (ie. with low overfitting) then there should not be much difference between the accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is overfitting to your training data. You need to try to tune the hyperpharameters so it will get a good accuracy when the you split the data. Otherwise model is not that useful.